# What do I return for function field value?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have a function field, but I don't know what should the function return.

Here's my code:

the function:

```
def _property_expense_preset_expenses(self, cr, uid, ids, expenses, arg, context):
    spus = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
    _spu = False
    for spu in spus:
    _spu = spu

    if(_spu):
        expenses_acc = {}
        property_expense_presets = _spu.property_expense_presets
        for property_expense_preset in property_expense_presets:
            expenses = property_expense_preset.expense_preset.expenses
            for expense in expenses:
            expenses_acc[expense.id] = expense
        return expenses_acc
    else:
        return {}
```

The field definition:

```
'expenses'      : fields.function(
                _property_expense_preset_expenses,
                type='one2many',
                obj="property.expense",
                method=True,
                string='Expenses'
            ),
```

The code above doesn't work, it raises an error : `KeyError: 788`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like all function fields, it must return a dictionary with an entry and value for every ID you get passed in ids, although your value can be False, None, []

In your case your functional field is declared as a one2many type which means your functional field must return a dictionary with an entry per id and the value, a list of integers that represent the ids of the related table, in your case, property.expense.

A very common pattern is:

```
def _property_expense_preset_expenses(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context = None):
    res = {}
    for spu in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context = context):
        res[spu.id] = []
        for preset in spu.property_expense_presets:
            res[spu.id].extend([x.id for x in preset.expense_preset.expenses])

    return res
```

Assuming ids contains 1,2,3 you will get a result of
{1: [...], 2: [...], 3: []}

Where each list contains the integer ids of the expenses or an empty list if there are none.

As a general comment, I note your code doesn't default the context argument to None or pass the context as a named argument to the browse method - it is important to do both.

Comment: Now that's the real answer! Thanks mate. But you missed `res = {}` before the `for`.

Comment: Hah, well spotted sir!  That will teach me to answer in a hurry on the train.

Answer (score 1):

### What is Function Field? What return this functional field function?

> In OpenERP functional field is a **field** that return the **calculated/logical value** that value store into **table**. That value you **can not get directly**. **that's why** we want to **use function field** and **return some value**.

When you **inserting data** into object model functional field **call every time** defined function and that function logic code whatever you made and return that **functional field value**.

### Example

```
class me.branch(osv.osv):
    _name = "me.branch"
    _order = 'name'

    def _get_branch_name(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        r = {}
        for branch in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            r[branch.id] = branch.name.split('/')[-1]
        return r

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', required=True),
        'branch_name': fields.function(_get_branch_name, type='char', string='Branch', readonly=1, store=True),
    }
```

Above example code **`branch name (eg. saas/demo/rarone )`** already exist in **`another table`**.

But I want to get that **`branch name`** only **`last slash (/)`** after string **`(rarone)`** and store into **`this table`** only.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the one2many type? What value do I set for `r[branch.id] = ` when I use the `type='one2many'`. I'm sorry but the first sentence of your description doesn't make sense.

Comment: for your requirement i wanna make demo example. this not possible at now sorry. even if i made i put here.

Comment: Can you just tell me what to do with the `expense` object that is already available and is already set to `expenses_acc[expense.id]`? My code is already similar to yours. It just needs a little tweak with the `expense` object because idk what to do with it.

Comment: @William i have knowledge about this but mostly i work on controller or web so i suggest you ask your question on http://help.openerp.com/questions/